# Couldn't find image with CID in windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, windows-services

I am testing the sending of an email with images using CID tag, I make a desktop application that only runs the mail, the program asked me to also place them in the debug folder of the project apart from the folder where I put them, Now I send it to a windows service but it tells me that

> Could not find file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\ img.png

I already put the image in that folder but it still gives me the same error, the image is type .png, this is my email code

```html
private void SendMAil()
        {

            string htmlBody = "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
"<html xmlns = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>" +
            "<head>" +
 "<meta http - equiv = 'Content-Type' content = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'/>" +
      "<title> Demystifying Email Design</title>" +
         "<meta name = 'viewport' content = 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'/>" +
            "</head>" +
            "<body style = 'margin: 0; padding: 0;'>" +
  "<table align = 'center' border = '0' cellpadding = '0' cellspacing = '0' width = '900' > " +
                        "<tr>" +
         "<td align='left' bgcolor='#F8F8F8' style='padding: 15px 0 15px 0;border-bottom-width:6px;border-bottom-color:#225100;border-bottom-style:solid;'>" +
          " <img  src=\"cid:img\"' width='90' height='40'>" +
         "</td>" +
        "</tr>" +
                         "<tr>" +
         "<td bgcolor = '#ffffff' style='padding:30px 30px 65px 30px'>" +
         "HELLO!!!"+
          "</td>" +
         "</tr>" +
                          "<tr>" +
         "<td bgcolor = '#FFFFFF' align='center' style='padding: 15px 0 15px 0;border-top-width:1px;border-top-color:#FA5300;border-top-style:solid;'>" +           
          "</td>" +
         "</tr>" +
           "</table>" +
        "</body>" +
            "</html>";
            AlternateView avHtml = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString
               (htmlBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

            LinkedResource inline = new LinkedResource("img.png", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
            inline.ContentId = "img";
            avHtml.LinkedResources.Add(inline);

            Attachment att1 = new Attachment(@"img\img.png");
            att1.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;

            mail.From = new MailAddress("xx@xx.com");
            mail.To.Add("xx@xx.com");
            mail.Subject = "Alerta Estado Tags";
            mail.Body = inline.ContentId;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Credentials =
                    new NetworkCredential("xx@xx.com", "****"),
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 000,
                EnableSsl = true
            };
            smtp.Send(mail);
            mail.Dispose();
        }
```

Where do I put the images? and What would be the path?

Answer (score 1):

Please review your code, you are using 2 paths for the `img.png` file, once under without specifying any additional path, which will result in the program trying to search the file under the current working directory (system32 in your case) and once searching inside the `img` folder (which should also be in your current working directory).

There are other issues in your code example,

1. you are not associating the `avHtml` to the email message anywhere.
   `mail.AlternateViews.Add`
2. where do you initializing the `mail` object?

But the most important, is how do you execute your program?
I assume you are using the windows command line and dragging the program with its full path, which causes your current working directory to stay under System32 (which is the default directory of `CMD` when running as Administrator.

Therefore, it looks for `img.png` and `img/img.png` under System32

Answer (score 1):

The cid tag is used for resources embedded in the email itself. So you  have to add the image as an attachment with a certain code (don't have it at the ready at the moment).
That said: don't use it. It's obsolete and blocked by many email clients. Dump your pictures on a webserver and just link to them.